# What does `(pred[:, 2:4] > min_wh).all(1)` do in YOLO (Deep Learning)?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, yolo

I am using yoloV3 under pytorch. I encountered this code `(pred[:, 2:4] > min_wh).all(1)` and do not know its function. Can anyone help? Thanks!

My concern is the use of `().all(1)`. I know `.all()` or `.any()`, but do not know `.all(1)`. Please explain `.all(1)`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.BoolTensor.all

there is `all(dim)` with first parameter `dim`. Which means it is the same as `all()`, but only on the selected dimension. It is basically used to select predictions (**rows**) on which **both** width and height are bigger than `min_wh`.

In your case `pred` has shape `(number_of_predictions, 7)` or

```
[
[x, y, w, h, object_conf, class_conf, class],
[x, y, w, h, object_conf, class_conf, class],
...
]
```

After `pred[:, 2:4] > min_wh`  the result will be something like

```
[
[True, False],
[True, True],
[False, False],
...
]
```

we want to select rows which have both width and height bigger than `min_wh`, thus we need to use `all(1)`.

Because

`all()` will give you `True` if all the elements are `True`, `False` otherwise

`all(0)` will give you tensor with shape `(2,)`, for example `[True, False]`. First element will be `True` if all elements in the first **column** are `True`, `False` otherwise. Second element will be `True` if all elements in the second **column** are `True`, `False` otherwise.

and `all(1)` will give you tensor with shape `(number_of_predictions,)`,
where each element is `True` only if all the elements in the row are `True`.

Comment: I have edited my question. My concern is the use of `.all(1)`, thanks.